# UserWarning: The soupsieve package is not installed. CSS selectors cannot be used

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

hey guys i need your help, i'm making my first steps in web-scraping area.
when i'm trying to follow a youtube tutorial video of web-scraping i got this warning.
i already installed soupsieve and BeautifulSoup (pip install etc...), and i even get the correct result from the site i was scraping but still got this annoying warning, what should i do?
i'm using python 3, pycharm.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq`enter code here`;
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup;

my_url = 'https://www.newegg.com/Video-Cards-Video-Devices/Category/ID-38?Tpk=graphics%20card'
uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()
page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")
containers = page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"item-container"})

for container in containers:
    title_container = container.findAll("a",{"class":"item-title"})
    prodact_name = title_container[0].text
    shipping_container = container.findAll("li",{"class":"prics-ship"})
    print("title: " + prodact_name)
```

Answer (score 1):

First run `sudo pip install --upgrade pip`

I tried "pip install beautifulsoup4" & "pip install soupsieve" both appear to be installed OK.

Answer (score 1):

ya, this happens when you install the package for 1 version and not for others.

this happens with me also, as usual, I am here to get the answer, but I also know that I have the pip already install, and the answer also saying the same,

Then I try to use **python3 project.py** then I get no Error.

If you are using **python project.py Use python3 project.py** and the problem get resolved easily

Answer (score 0):

I also got the error that soupsieve is not installed. What worked for me is to use Visual Studio to run the code then it worked properly for me.

Also, try and add your saved working file path to *system envrionment variables*: `C:\Users\<your username>\Desktop\Projects\pythoProject1\view`

Answer (score 0):

Try `pip3 install soupsieve` or `python -m pip install soupsieve`
If it didn't work, perhaps you have a separate bs4 folder in your environment. In this case, you need to copy the soupsieve folder from the `/lib/python3/dist-packages` path into your local bs4 folder.